# vicon_bridge serviceClient FAIL!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have written a simple [serviceClient](https://github.com/lakehanne/Vicon/blob/master/vicon_bridge/src/grabpose_client.cpp) subscriber to [Vicon_bridge services](http://wiki.ros.org/vicon_bridge#Services). Basically, I want to have a clent that retrieves the pose information from the vicon_bridge Service Server.

I have tried all I know but every time I run the code, the error condition returns as so:

> [ INFO] [1448305105.714274705]: waitForService: Service [/vicon/Superchicko/headcore] has not been advertised, waiting...

even though the vicon_bridge node is clearly advertising since

> rostopic echo /vicon_bridge/Superchicko/headCore

does show me the pose messages in another terminal.

I see on the [roscpp documentation page](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#aa3376eeca609c4985255cecfaadcbcc5) that when subscribing to a ServiceServer within a class, the Service client should be constructed as follows:

> ServiceClient ros::NodeHandle::serviceClient  (   const std::string &     service_name,
> bool    persistent = false,
> const M_string &    header_values = M_string()
> )

The thing is when I try this, I get no calls either  from the `vicon_bridge::viconGrabPose`. Could anyone help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221396/vicon_bridge-serviceclient-fail!/) by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2015-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's fixed. Code is available [on my page](https://github.com/lakehanne/Vicon/blob/master/vicon_bridge/src/grabpose_client.cpp).

The service server is advertised as `"/vicon/grab_vicon_pose/"` and not `vicon/subject_name/segment_name`.

My bad!

---

Originally posted by [lakehanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/22838/lakehanne/) with karma: 152 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0